# innodb transactions and room reservation

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I'm currently reading a lot about transactions in InnoDB, at this time i only ever used myISAM tables so i'm not very used to all this:

Here is my table scheme :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservations` (
  `id_reservation` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_room` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_from` date NOT NULL,
  `date_to` date NOT NULL,
  `cancelled` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_reservation`),
  KEY `id_room` (`id_appartement`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now let's say i want to INSERT a new reservation for room ID 15, from 2012-02-15 to 2012-02-24, here's what I think i should do based on what i read :

1. start transaction :

   ```
   START TRANSACTION;
   ```
2. INSERT the row

   ```
   INSERT INTO reservations SET 
     id_room = 15, 
     date_from = '2012-02-15', 
     date_to='2012-02-24', 
     cancelled='N';
   ```
3. check if there is a reservation conflicting with the reservation i just made

   ```
   SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE 
     id_room = 15 
     AND cancelled = 'N' 
     AND date_from < '2012-02-24' AND date_to > '2012-02-15' 
     AND id_reservation <> LAST_INSERT_ID();
   ```
4. if not, `COMMIT;`
5. else, `ROLLBACK;`

Problem is, in default isolation mode (REPEATABLE-READ), once i start the transaction, i won't see any other INSERT made outside this very transaction.
So what would happen if, just after step 1), another user inserts a conflicting reservation ?

Maybe i should use READ-COMMITED in this case? but wouldn't this lead to issues as well ?
Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is fine, but you need to add one table and one query to your transaction.

The table needs one row for each `id_room`. You probably already have that table.

So, right after START TRANSACTION do:

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE id_room=15 FOR UPDATE;
```

That will block the next guy trying to put in a reservation for the same room until you either COMMIT or ROLLBACK your transaction, as long as the next guy also uses this FOR UPDATE syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Very smart approach :)

Comment: This will lock two transactions with two independent time durations for the same room. That is the undesirable behavior in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say I use php scripts to access my database using PDO and transactions for a reservation system where you book a room for some time. The slots are for 30-minute periods but the room will be booked for at least one hour. So once it is booked the time slot before it is also disabled because it cannot be booked for only 30 minutes. 
Assuming two or more customers try to access and book a certain time slot or one before it, will the first one succeed and the others will be rejected meaning the script will end or will they wait after the first one finishes and if he indeed books the time slot they will be rejected when they try again or in the case he decides against booking the room the second will select and go through the same sequence of events